# Apache - Rerouting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, apache2

Ok, this is some recursive thing, and I don't know how to do this in Apache.
I want this: I have some folders, let say `test.web.com`, `website`. Now this is what should happen:

1) When visiting `(.*).(.*).[...].test.web.com`, check whether that directory exists. If not, try whether `(.*).[...].test.web.com` exists. (So one level higher). Repeat step 1 in that case. So for example, when I visit `a.b.test.web.com`, it will first check if `a.b.test.web.com` exists, if exists, it will load that folder. If not, it will test for `b.test.web.com`, if that does not exists it will test for `test.web.com` which finally exists!

2) When still no folder exists, use the `website` folder. So for example, when I go to `bla.web.com`, it cannot find such a directory, so it will load `website`.

How can I get this working?

Comment: You should ask this question on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Are the dots supposed to be slashes? Or are you literally requesting `http://your.domain.com/a.b.test.web.com/`?

Comment: No, I ment `http://a.b.test.web.com/`.

Comment: Or `https://a.b.test.web.com/`.

Comment: Do all of these hosts share a document root?

Comment: So when someone goes to `http://a.b.test.web.com/`, what directory is supposed to be checked if it exists?

Comment: First `/var/www/a.b.test.com`, then `/var/www/b.test.com` and then `/var/www/test.com`. If that not exists, then `/var/www/website/`.